# Start Application with service

Tags: c#, service, winlogon

i want to run an application made in c# winform through service.i have done the code but the application does not get started even service successfully gets started and no exception is thrown.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("starting Kb");
            try
            {
                Process myProcess = new Process();
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Invisual E. Inc\KeyboardSetup\keyboard.exe";//Exe Path 
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;


                myProcess.Start();
                ProcessWindowStyle ws = myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle;
                if (ws == ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden)
                    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

                eventLog1.WriteEntry("started");

            }
            catch (Exception c)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(c.Message);
            }
        }
```

Log file does not show any exceptions.

Purpose is to start the application at the welcome screen of window so that user can use custom made keyboard .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What operating system?  From Vista and beyond you cannot create GUI from services (it's a security flaw and ugly...)  There is a user 0 session that shows gui started by services from vista onwards.

Why not create a registry entry and/or startup entry for your app to start when the user who installed your app logs in?  Or follow the [info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about implementing an interactive service.

Comment: i need this application to run at login screen.when user has not logged in

Comment: Is it for an authentication process?  Otherwise for security reasons NO gui can be run from the windows machine until a user logs in.  If you are trying to create an "application box" then you actually need to auto login a user to get the OS.

Comment: If it is for authentication then you need to create a GINA dll.  But my understanding is that C/C++ is required to do this properly.

Comment: this is a keyboard that has limited number of keys so that user has option to run it and enter limited output.Is it possible that i replace some how the accecibility keyboard options to open this?

Comment: This application is just another on screen keybiard

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a GINA dll, which will then run a custom app that the user can use to login using your special keyboard.  I'd also take a look a embedded windows builds, they can be tailored to your application http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-products-for-developers.aspx

Comment: If you install an IME keyboard and enable it in windows, this should run at startup from my understanding (i.e once it's installed an enabled, it will show up when the user clicks on the dialog.)

Comment: ok then if it is flaw or security risk in vista or 7 should it work for win XP because it is for XP

Answer (score 0):

A service normally runs under a user other than the logged in user therefore the service doesn't have a desktop available to display any windows form, hence the reason t isn't being displayed.

I think you will need to find another way as although a winforms app can start a service I dont believe it can be done the other way around.

Regards

AJ